# how to know if you are in a nested ssh?

Tags: ssh

I am interested to know if there is any way that I can find out if I am in a nested SSH session and how many of them?

For example, From *host2* `ssh user1@host1` then from *host1* `ssh user1@host2` ends up in *host1*, but actually I can exit to go to *host2*.

How can I know that I am in such a situation (in a nested ssh session), other than exit command of course?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not a perfect solution because not all SSH clients support this; and these that do can be configured differently. Still…

[`ssh` from OpenSSH supports the following](https://man.openbsd.org/ssh#ESCAPE_CHARACTERS):

> ESCAPE CHARACTERS
>
> When a pseudo-terminal has been requested, `ssh` supports a number of functions through the use of an escape character.
>
> A single tilde character can be sent as `~~` or by following the tilde by a character other than those described below. The escape character must always follow a newline to be interpreted as special. The escape character can be changed in configuration files using the `EscapeChar` configuration directive or on the command line by the `-e` option.
>
> The supported escapes (assuming the default `~`) are:
>
> […]
>
> `~^Z`
> Background `ssh`.
>
> […]
>
> `~C`
> Open command line. […] `!command` allows the user to execute a local command if the `PermitLocalCommand` option is enabled in `ssh_config(5)`. Basic help is available, using the `-h` option.
>
> […]

Assuming all the chained SSH clients support this, and assuming pseudo-terminals have been requested, you can tell the number of connections by observing how many tilde characters are "consumed" before the actual tilde appears in the current command line. Remember the tilde must always follow a newline to be interpreted as special. My tests show that each connection consumes one escape character.

E.g. if after <kbd>Enter</kbd> you need to send <kbd>~</kbd> four times to get one `~` on the screen, then it means there are three chained connections.

You can background any of them by sending <kbd>Enter</kbd>, a respective number of <kbd>~</kbd> and then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>. This will place you in the respective shell where you can investigate where you came from (`env | grep ^SSH_`), where you are (`uname -a`, `hostname`, …), what the backgrounded command is (`jobs`). Run `fg` to get the connection back. What you can do depends on the shell and how you did run the respective `ssh`, I won't elaborate.

It would be nice if there was an escape function that makes `ssh` itself print basic information about the connection (similar to `~#`). It seems there is no such functionality (yet).

With `~C` (`C` here means capital C, <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>) and `!command` you may be able to investigate without sending any `ssh` to the background. Note the default value of [`PermitLocalCommand`](https://man.openbsd.org/ssh_config.5#PermitLocalCommand) is `no`. AFAIK you cannot change it after the connection is established, so think ahead.